# $stateParams getting null after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

When passing $stateParams through $state.go it is  getting correctly when i click the link directly, but getting null after page refresh or open through another window.

I have the following function:

```
$scope.urlvalues = function(url,page) {
    var result = {url:url, page:page};
        $state.go("detailpage", result);
}
```

And my state looks like this:

```
.state('detailpage', {
            url: "/page/overview",
            templateUrl: "/page_details.html",
            controller: "PageDetailsController",
            params: {
                    url: null,
                    page: null
                    },         
        })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your urlvalues function located?

Comment: In another Controller named PageController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try:

```
.state('detailpage', {
        url: "/page/overview/:url/:page",
        templateUrl: "/page_details.html",
        controller: "PageDetailsController",

    })
```

Then, when you go to the page the url will be set and will be there when you refresh.

Comment: What if you don't want to pass the params in the URL?

Comment: optional params get a "?" like `/page/overview/:url?/:page?`

Comment: No, I mean what if you need to pass objects as params to certain states. Refreshing the state would lose that state param. Is there a way to maintain the $state.params.myObject without storing it to localStorage for instance?