# Angular JS UI-Routing with stateparams not working after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angular-ui-router with angular for routing in MEAN application

- angular: 1.6.2,
- angular-ui-router: 0.4.2

Having following state:

```
.state('myposts', {            
    url: '/your-posts',    
    controller:'PostListController',    
    templateUrl:'post-list.template.html'    
})    

.state('postdetail', {    
     url: '/post/:postId',    
     controller:'PostDetailController',    
     templateUrl:'postdetail.template.html',    
     resolve:{    
        postdetail: ['Post', '$stateParams', function (Post, $stateParams) {    
             var url = '/api/posts/edit/' + $stateParams.postId;    
             return Post.get(url);    
        }]    
     }    
})
```

In post-list.template.html listed all posts in table and there is an link to edit particular post by using the following

```
<a ui-sref="postdetail({ postId: post._id })" class="btn btn-default">
```

It makes an transition from **myposts** to **postdetail** with **postId** parameter.

Actual URL http://localhost:8886/#/post/58d5167bf05b904a52158f58

Here **postId** is 58d5167bf05b904a52158f58

Resolve post with postId = 58d5167bf05b904a52158f58 in resolve property of ui-router and inject in **PostDetailController** controller

```
function PostDetailController($scope, $state, $stateParams, postdetail, Post){
    $scope.post = postdetail;
    ....
}
```

It works normally first time, but not working when i refresh the page having url
http://localhost:8886/#/post/58d5167bf05b904a52158f58

Using **express server ^4.13.4**,

Anyone having solution of above problems, why it is happening

Thanks

Comment: [Seesm to be similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602345/angularjs-ui-router-stateparams-invisible-loses-on-page-refresh)

Comment: It's not the same issue though; in Aniket's case, the parameter comes from the url, while in the linked case it's an optional, invisible parameter (in which case it's understandable since the app is fully reloaded after a refresh)

Comment: Yes parameter is availabe in the url, even though angular bootstrap app again, state not resolving the data in resolve property.  After refreshing  the page, the form which was filled first time with resolve data, not showing the form(after refresh)

Comment: Sorry, but is isn't enough information to go on. Could you show the rest of the configuration where the `postdetail` state is defined? Also, could you describe the flow when the code in question is working correctly and provide additional code samples if you are transitioned from another state in case when code is working correctly?

Comment: I think you may need something like `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`

Comment: finally got solution, checked via state event                 
    `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, 
        fromState, fromParams, error) {    
        console.dir(error);
    });`     
       
It showing that **Post** service $injector problem , before i was loading the **Post** service via **$oclazyload** module, so i mention globally, now its working.
Thank you for support