# Passing object in $stateParams url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass an object as param in my url, but i am getting this weird formation.

> http://localhost:8080/#/%5Bobject%20Object%5D => [object Object]

Below is my code on how i am sending the object.

```
var user = {"user":item};
$state.go("myState",user);
```

In my routes

```
.state('myState',{
   url: "/:user",
   templateUrl: "user.html",
   controller: 'User',                  
});
```

When i try to access the view user page, i get the above url and the data is not able to be accessed via `$stateParams.user` as its a string `[object Object]`

I am using ui-router version v0.2.15 with angular 1.3.4

Comment: The param has to work in an URL context so it must be a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to pass an object from one state's controller to another, you can't use the URL state parameters as these must be a string in order to work in the URL.

What you can do is use the `params` state config property.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    url: 'whatever',
    templateUrl: 'user.html',
    controller: 'User',
    params: {
        user: null
    }
});
```

Now you *can* transition to the `myState` state and pass a complex object

```
$state.go('myState', {user: item});
```

and your `User` controller can reference `$stateParams.user`.

Comment: This is how i was doing, the problem is when you refresh the page... it would loose the data... and.. here is a thread on this.. but its not working in my case.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979798/stateparams-getting-null-after-page-refresh